# Regex to parse simple markdown with escaped characters without look-behind

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

> **Note:** This has to work in JavaScript RegExp

I have to parse string like this:

```
yo (p:abc-123-def) meets  \(p:2) \(in the cinema\) \\ (p:3) (p:4\) won't
```

What I need to extract are all `(<entity>:<id>)` markups but ignore escaped things like `\(in the ciname\)` or `\\`. From the above example, the regex should only match

```
(p:abc-123-def)
(p:3)
```

but not `\(p:2)` or `\(p:4)` since the brackets are escaped.

Now, I am still able to modify that markup so if there is a simpler way to do the whole thing I'm open to suggestions. If not, I'd need to be able to get those `(<entity>:<id>)` markups from a regex.

Something like this

```
(?<!\\)\([^(?<!\\)\(]*\)
```

would work but look-behind groups are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: `/\([a-z]+:[0-9]+\)/g` would be enough, wouldn't it?

Comment: @str Actually, the `id` can be UUID-like.

Comment: Then match it with `[0-9a-z-]+`.

Comment: @str But this expression would match `\(person:2)` - this should not match because the opening bracket is escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can get complex when backslashes are repeated many times, like: `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\(p:1)`. You would need to know whether the number of backslashes is even or odd in order to know whether the `(` is escaped or not.

Secondly, the colon occurring within parentheses might be escaped as well, and would then not count(?).

So I would suggest to work with something like `(?:\\.|[^:)\\])*` which deals with escaped characters (`.`) and puts some requirements for unescaped characters, like `[^:)\\]`.

So this is the result:

[`(?<!\\)(?:\\.)*\((?:\\.|[^:)\\])*:(?:\\.|[^:)\\])*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/39nqF7/1)

This uses look-behind which is being supported in the latest versions of popular browsers.

If look-behind is not an option, then capture the character that precedes the potential backslashes, and make a capture group for the part you need:

[`(?:[^\\]|^)((?:\\.)*\((?:\\.|[^:)\\])*:(?:\\.|[^:)\\])*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/39nqF7/3)

So here you need to work with the first captured group.

Comment: Good point about the repeating backslashes. That regex got more complex than I was hoping for but I guess that one (without look-behind) will do it.

Answer (score 0):

This regex needs to work

```
/(?<!\\)\([a-zA-Z]+\:[0-9a-zA-Z_]+\)/g
```

**Edit: This code is javascript compiled.**

[Regexpr Fiddle](https://regexr.com/46och)

Comment: can you please check again?

Comment: The `_` should be `-` but besides that, this is unfortunately not valid syntax for JavaScript. This, `(?<!\\)\([^(?<!\\)\(]*\)`, from my question would work as well but not in JS.

Comment: This regex won't work on all browsers as stated by the warning in the fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to match what you don't want and to capture in a capturing group what you want to keep.

For example:

```
\\+\([^)]+\)|\([^)]+\\+\)|(\([^:]+:[^:]+\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f0uIut/3)

- `\\+\([^)]+\)` Match 1+ times a backslash followed by an opening `(` till `)`
- `|` Or
- `\([^)]+\\+\)` Match `(` till 1+ times a backslash and `)`
- `|` Or
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\([^:]+:[^:]+\)` Match `(`, not `:`, then `:` and again not `:` followed by `)`
- `)` Close capturing group

```js
const regex = /\\+\([^)]+\)|\([^)]+\\+\)|(\([^:]+:[^:]+\))/g;
const str = `yo (p:abc-123-def) meets  \\(p:2) \\(in the cinema\\) \\\\ (p:3) (p:4\\) won't`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (typeof(m[1]) != 'undefined') {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have noticed that the problem with my own solution is that the negative look-behinds were *capturing* groups. But if I make them non-capturing groups, the regex won't work anymore. So `(?<!\\)\([^\)]+(?<!\\)\)` works but `(?:<!\\)\([^\)]+(?:<!\\)\)` does not - no chance to make the second on work I guess? You solution seems like a good workaround though.

Comment: Btw there is still a mistake - `(p:4\)` would be matched too ^^ https://regex101.com/r/f0uIut/2

Comment: @displayname I have updated the regex to not match `(p:4\)` as well. Your regex would work in for example newer versions of chrome where lookbehinds are supported.